# An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Request has expired when I run the commend on AWS cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, port, backend

When I run the following shell script which can allow user to use port80 in aws, errors orruc:

```
MY_INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) # Get the ID of the instance for the environment, and store it temporarily.

MY_SECURITY_GROUP_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $MY_INSTANCE_ID --query 'Reservations[].Instances[0].SecurityGroups[0].GroupId' --output text) # Get the ID of the security group associated with the instance, and store it temporarily.

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $MY_SECURITY_GROUP_ID --protocol tcp --cidr 0.0.0.0/0 --port 80 # Add an inbound rule to the security group to allow all incoming IPv4-based traffic over port 80.

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $MY_SECURITY_GROUP_ID --ip-permissions IpProtocol=tcp,Ipv6Ranges='[{CidrIpv6=::/0}]',FromPort=80,ToPort=80 # Add an inbound rule to the security group to allow all incoming IPv6-based traffic over port 80.

MY_SUBNET_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $MY_INSTANCE_ID --query 'Reservations[].Instances[0].SubnetId' --output text) # Get the ID of the subnet associated with the instance, and store it temporarily.

MY_NETWORK_ACL_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-network-acls --filters Name=association.subnet-id,Values=$MY_SUBNET_ID --query 'NetworkAcls[].Associations[0].NetworkAclId' --output text) # Get the ID of the network ACL associated with the subnet, and store it temporarily.

aws ec2 create-network-acl-entry --network-acl-id $MY_NETWORK_ACL_ID --ingress --protocol tcp --rule-action allow --rule-number 10000 --cidr-block 0.0.0.0/0 --port-range From=80,To=80 # Add an inbound rule to the network ACL to allow all IPv4-based traffic over port 80. Advanced users: change this suggested rule number as desired.

aws ec2 create-network-acl-entry --network-acl-id $MY_NETWORK_ACL_ID --ingress --protocol tcp --rule-action allow --rule-number 10100 --ipv6-cidr-block ::/0 --port-range From=80,To=80 # Add an inbound rule to the network ACL to allow all IPv6-based traffic over port 80. Advanced users: change this suggested rule number as desired.
```

The error message is:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    19  100    19    0     0   1266      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1266
hello

An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Request has expired.
hello
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --group-id: expected one argument
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --group-id: expected one argument

An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Request has expired.

An error occurred (RequestExpired) when calling the DescribeNetworkAcls operation: Request has expired.
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --network-acl-id: expected one argument
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --network-acl-id: expected one argument


Process exited with code: 2

Pane is dead
```

I have try the code in a new environment, there is no any problem with it, what's wrong in my system? How can fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `allow user to use port80 in aws`

Comment: I had to open a new shell and enter `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in there. For some reason they weren't working in a shell that i had opened for a while

Comment: Im having this issue too.  i suspected it was my env vars, but then i have a script that automatically installs them right now, so that didnt make sense.  But your right, the env vars are gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different profiles, you would have to specify the profile in your command like shown below.

```
 aws --profile <my-profile> ec2 describe-instances ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[aws-credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APc56.png)

Recommend checking first if AWS managed temporary credentials is disabled. Then use named profiles

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the AWS session was expired. High possibility in enterprise environments due to IT policies.

Try updating the credentials information by creating a fresh session.